# Invoking Ansible roles in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ansible, roles, invoke

I am an architect completely new to DevOPS and CICD and my question may be not clear. My application vendor has provided some Ansible roles and playbooks. I have Jenkins server which is having a pipeline running a terraform scripts to provision the compute engines on GCP. After this provisioning I will have deploy my application provided by my vendor.

I have couple of questions here

1. Do you need separate server hosting ansible other than the Jenkins to execute the Ansible roles and playbook? Or Just a Ansible plug-in installed will suffice to execute these ansible roles
2. For application deployment on the target server provisioned by terraform , We need to tell fill those details dynamically to the hosts files of ansible? Have anyone tried this before or is there any other way.
3. My target servers where the application will be deployed will have both Windows and Linux. What integrations are required at jenkins level for application deployment pipeline to work?

Thanks,
Manoj

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. QuickNDirty response in a comment. 1- you don't need a seperate server. Ansible installed on jenkins server + jenkins ansible plugin will let you run your playbooks. 2- are you talking about a dynamic inventory (not sure I understand your question) ? There is an inventory plugin available for gcp: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/google/cloud/gcp_compute_inventory.html 3- the only real needed thing at jenkins level is ansible itself. Some modules may have specific python requirements at controller level (e.g. jenkins server in your case).

Comment: Regarding to your question :-

 1. One server will be enough no need for extra.
 2. What Details ? can you explain more please ?
 3. Define Integration ? as i understood no integration needed.

Comment: Thank you for your responses!! 2. Ansible roles will be executed for an application installation on the compute engines provisioned using a terraform script. We need inform the ansible to execute these roles on certain hosts and that needs to be defined on the host file. My question was around this to check if any one has tried to populate dynamically this host file after provisioning the compute engines using terraform.